# Latex code for table not working

Tags: tables, overleaf, debugging

I'm trying this table - [image]

Here's my latex code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}
\author{Ved}
\date{September 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Overall order \\ of reaction\end{tabular} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Units of rate constant (Remember \\ that time can be given in any units)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
0 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\[\\ \frac{mol}{dm^{3} \times time} =mol\ dm^{-3} \ time^{-1}\\ \]\end{tabular}          \\ \hline
1 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\[\\ \frac{1}{time} =time^{-1}\\ \]\end{tabular}                                         \\ \hline
2 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\[\\ \frac{dm^{3}}{mol\times time} =dm^{3} \ mol^{-1} \ time^{-1}\\ \]\end{tabular}      \\ \hline
3 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\[\\ \frac{dm^{6}}{mol^{2} \times time} =dm^{6} \ mol^{-2} \ time^{-1}\\ \]\end{tabular} \\ \hline
n &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\[\\ (\text{concentration})^{1-n} \times time^{-1}\]\\ can also be written as - \\ \[\left(\frac{mol}{dm^{3}}\right)^{1-n} \times time^{-1}\\ \]\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Overleaf is telling me that I've made an error -
[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]
[image: Error 3]
Can someone please debug my code? I've made an error somewhere and can't seem figure out where it is.

Comment: why have you all the nested tabular????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small variant of @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer. Changed are

- table style,
- packages `amsmath` and `siunitx` are loaded as `tabularray` libraries
- all instruction for table style are collected in table preamble

It works fine with `tabularray` local installed package version 2022C as well with package version installed now on Overleaf (tested).

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec = {Q[c, m, mode=math] Q[l, m,  mode=dmath]},
  row{1}  = {mode=text},
  row{2-Z}= {rowsep=5pt}
            }
{Overall order\\ of reaction} 
    & {Units of rate constant\\ (Remember that time can be given in any units)}                     \\
0   & \frac{\unit{mol}}{\unit{dm^{3}} \times \text{time}} =\unit{mol. dm^{-3}} \text{time}^{-1}     \\
1   & \frac{1}{\text{time}} =\text{time}^{-1}                                                       \\
2   & \frac{\unit{dm^{3}}}{\unit{mol}\times \text{time}} =\unit{dm^{3}.mol^{-1}}\text{time}^{-1}    \\
3   & \frac{\unit{dm^{6}}}{\unit{mol^{2}} \times \text{time}} =\unit{dm^{6}.mol^{-2}}\text{time}^{-1} \\
n   & \begin{aligned}
        & (\text{concentration})^{1-n} \times \text{time}^{-1} \text{ can also be written}\\
        & \text{as }\left(\frac{\unit{mol}}{\unit{dm^{3}}}\right)^{1-n} \times \text{time}^{-1}
      \end{aligned}                        \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page borders)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you can't use `\[...\]` inside your cells. You could use `$\displaystyle ...$` instead, however I think you will get a nicer result with the `tabularray` package.

You are also using `\text{...}` in your code, but the `amsmath` package is missing in your preamble.

And finally, you might want to have a look at the `siunitx` package to correctly set your units in upright font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{test}
\author{Ved}
\date{September 2022}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={Q[c]X[mode=dmath]},
  vlines,
  hlines,
  cells={valign=m}
}
Overall order of reaction & \SetCell{mode=text} Units of rate constant (Remember that time can be given in any units)\\ 
0 &  \frac{\unit{mol}}{\unit{dm^{3}} \times \text{time}} =\unit{mol. dm^{-3}} \text{time}^{-1}       \\
1 & \frac{1}{\text{time}} =\text{time}^{-1}                                         \\ 
2 & \frac{\unit{dm^{3}}}{\unit{mol}\times \text{time}} =\unit{dm^{3}.mol^{-1}}\text{time}^{-1}      \\ 
3 & \frac{\unit{dm^{6}}}{\unit{mol^{2}} \times \text{time}} =\unit{dm^{6}.mol^{-2}}
\text{time}^{-1} \\ 
n & (\text{concentration})^{1-n} \times \text{time}^{-1} $ can also be written as $ \displaystyle \left(\frac{\unit{mol}}{\unit{dm^{3}}}\right)^{1-n} \times \text{time}^{-1} \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Overleaf still has installed too old version of `tabularray` package, so `mode=dmath` instruction doesn't work. as expected (cells with math are black). I hope, that they will update their installation until the end of the (this) year ...

Comment: @Zarko They just updated to TL2022

Comment: Really? I just try your nice code (+1) but it still not work as expected. I'm use Overleaf very rare, so I'm not familiar with it. What I should do, that I will get access to recent installed Overleaf?

Comment: @Zarko New projects will automatically use TL22, for older ones you can select it from the sidebar

Comment: Thank you very much. As you can see from my answer, I figured out this. Now your and mine code can be compiled on Overleaf too. Thank you for information!